# Securely store values in Microsoft team apps

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I'm planning to launch a Microsoft Teams app. Users will authenticate by providing a project ID and API key like this. I'm wondering what the best practice is for storing this information inside Microsoft Teams and later accessing it to add it in the header while making an API call.

```js
if (value && value.submitType === "authentication") {
    const apiKey = value.apiKey;
    const projectId = value.projectId;

    context.turnState.set('apiKey', apiKey);
    context.turnState.set('projectId', projectId);

    await context.sendActivity('Authentication successful. Your API key and Project ID have been securely stored.');
}
```

When I try to access it later, I'm getting "undefined." I have tried two approaches:

```
console.log("projectId first approach:", context.turnState.get('projectId'));
console.log("projectId second approach:", context.activity.value.projectId);
```

Comment: Could you please check these docs if it helps? 1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp 2.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-custom-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0